# Totalling multiple products within a singled column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

```
=UNIQUE(D:D)
=ArrayFormula(sumif(D2:D4315,{K10:K247},G:G))
```

So my quantities of each product needed is in column G

Column D has the product names, and column K is the list of unique names.

So my thought process is Column K highlights the unique name of each product.

Column D is the column the formula scans to highlight which named products to sum.

And column G is the individual quantities of item needed.

However it doesn't seem that the quantity is correct just by testing a few.

Comment: try: `=ArrayFormula(sumif(D:D,{K10:K247},G:G))`

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUMIF(D:D, {K10:K247}, G:G))
```